# Your are given the root nodes of two binary search trees. Determine if both trees store the same numbers

Tags: java, data-structures, binary-search-tree

The answer needs to be iterative, not recursive and the trees don't have to have the same structure, only the same numbers. I think I need to use a vertex traversal, but I am not sure how to implement that without using recursion.

This is what I had, but it doesn't pass the given tests. Also, I can't use any helper functions.

```
    Node leftTree = t1;
    Node rightTree = t2;
    
    if(t1 == null && t2 == null)
        return true;
    else if (t1 != null && t2 == null)
        return false;
    else if (t1 == null && t2 != null)
        return false;
    else
    {
        if(leftTree.key == rightTree.key && problem1(leftTree.left, rightTree.left) == true 
                && problem1(leftTree.right, rightTree.right) == true) 
            return true;
    }
    return false;
```

Answer (score 0):

The recursion, where you compare left with left and right with right, will not work, because you can have the same keys but in a different topology. You need to visit the nodes in-order in the two trees in parallel.

One way of going through a tree without using recursion or extra memory is via a Morris traversal, where you temporarily put a tree in the rightmost position of its left subtree, and "return" from the recursion by following the right pointer there.

Here is an implementation in C, because I have one lying around. In Java it won't be that different. The `rightmost_to()` function returns the rightmost node in the left child of the current node, or the current node itself. You use it put the current node in the right child there, so when you get down to that point, going right emulates returning from the recursion.

```c
void morris(stree *t)
{
  struct node *curr = *t;
  while (curr) {
    if (!curr->left) {
      printf("%d\n", curr->value);
      curr = curr->right;
    } else {
      stree pred = *rightmost_to(&curr->left, curr);
      assert(pred->right == 0 || pred->right == curr);
      if (pred->right == 0) {
        pred->right = curr;
        curr = curr->left;
      } else {
        printf("%d\n", curr->value);
        pred->right = 0;
        curr = curr->right;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You will visit each node in order, without recursion, and without using extra memory. Whenever you recurse, you put the node you are in at the rightmost position, so you automatically come back to it. You can recognise that you are seeing the node for the second time because you find it when searching for the rightmost. Then you restore the tree instead of going left once more.

If you need to compare two trees, have two current nodes, and you should be fine. It does use an extra function, `rightmost_to()`, but it is a simple loop that you can easily embed without any issues. It is a line or two if you do that.

If you are allowed to put a parent pointer in the nodes, I think you can also traverse the trees without using extra memory doing something like this:

```c
#define left_child(t) \
  ((t)->parent && (t)->parent->left == (t))
void parent_traverse(stree t)
{
  enum { DOWN, UP } state = DOWN;
  while (t) {
    switch (state) {
      case DOWN:
        // Recurse as far left as we can...
        while (t->left) { t = t->left; }
        // Emit the leaf we find there
        printf("(,%d,", t->value); // VISIT
        // Then go right, if we can, or up if we can't.
        if (t->right) { t = t->right; }
        else          { state = UP; }
        break;

      case UP:
        if (!t->parent) return; // we have returned to the root...
        if (left_child(t)) {
          // Returning from a left child, we emit the parent
          t = t->parent;
          printf(",%d,", t->value); // VISIT
          // Then we go right if we can't, or continue up
          // (t is already the parent) if we cannot.
          if (t->right) { t = t->right; state = DOWN; }
        } else {
          // Returning from a right child just means going up
          t = t->parent;
        }
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

Sorry, it is C again, but just look at how `t` is updated to its left, right or parent node as we run through the tree. I cut that out of some code I have, and I might have copied it wrong, but you should get the idea. You can keep track of which direction you are moving, and essentially move along the "edge" of the tree, down left edges, under them and up, then down to the right, turn, and move up, and so on. If you have the state for both trees, you should be able to do that traversal in parallel in the two. Everwhere the code "visits" a node, you will compare the two nodes.

I don't know how useful this is, but it is at least a couple of ways that you can compare two trees with only constant extra memory usage and no recursion.

Of course, if it is a simple assignment and the time complexity doesn't matter, run through one tree and look up in the other in O(n log n) (balanced) or O(n^2). :)

Comment: Okay, this is what I got, it still doesn't pass the given tests. I forgot to note that it should return a boolean value (true or false).

Comment: Node curr = t1;
        while(curr != null)
        {
            if(curr.left == null)
                curr = curr.right;
            else
            {
                Node pre = curr;
                while(curr.right != null)
                    pre = pre.right;
                
                if(pre.right.equals(0))
                {
                    pre.right = curr;
                    curr = curr.left;
                }
                else
                {
                    pre.right.key = 0;
                    curr = curr.right; } } } } return true

Comment: @Ryan I can’t figure out what that code should be doing. Sorry. Is it searching for the rightmost?

Comment: It’s like what the question is, determine if 2 BST, store the same numbers. With the given nodes t1 and t2.

Comment: @Ryan your code only looks at one tree, so it is not doing that. Clearly. Can you visit all nodes in one tree without recursion? Does that work for you?

Comment: Can you give an example to what the code should look like? I don’t know how to do that without recursion.

Comment: @Ryan both the functions in my answer do this. They iterate through the tree and prints the node values in order.

Comment: @Ryan to get Java you mostly have to change -> to . and 0 to null. You need a different implementation of rightmost_to because you can’t get a pointer to a pointer, so you need to get the node instead, and then figure out if it is a left or right tree when you update. It can be a left tree if cur’s left tree doesn’t have a right tree